# Pass DataContext to the Converter Parameter in Silverlight 5

Tags: mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

I am new to silverlight as well as in MVVM. I am using Silverlight 5 with MVVM Light toolkit.

The Binding of my usercontrol is applied from a View and want to send this Binding as a ConverterParameter to Converter.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it because of ConverterParameter is not DependencyProperty.
My advice is pass something another as value of parameter.